# Member list initialization with inheritance?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, constructor

I want to build a constructor for class C as you can see on the last line. I don't understand why it doesn't work. If I delete  :B(b, A bb):b(b), bb(bb) it's fine, but then I can't give values for b and bb. Also, I'm not sure how to create an object with all parameters in the main function.

```
class A
{
protected:
   int a, aa;
public:
   A();
   A(int a, int aa);
   ~A();
   friend class B;
   friend class C;
};
class B
{
protected:
   int b;
   A bb;
public:
   B();
   B(int b, A bb);
   ~B();
};
class C: class B
{
private:
   int c;
   A cc;
public:
   C();
   C(int c, A cc);
   ~C();
  };

C:C(int c, A cc):c(c), cc(cc):B(b, A bb):b(b), bb(bb){}  // I tried smth like this, but obviously it doesn't work

int main()

{ A aaa(1, 2);
C(3, A); ///how can i set values for B-members
```

Comment: What you wrote isn't valid. You need to pass variables to `B`'s constructor: i.e.: `C::C(int c, A cc) : B(c, cc), c(c), cc(cc) {}`. PS: really recommend better variable names.

Comment: `A(int b, A bb);` makes no sense in a `class B`.  And `B(b, A bb)` certainly makes no sense in a member initialization list.

Answer (score 1):

First, the inheritance of C from B is broken, it needs to `class C: B`, not `class C: class B`. So you got compiler errors even before it reached the initialization lists. You can't expect us to fix your code that's *not* part of your problem...

But to the main point: Remember that when you're constructing an instance of subclass C of a class B, you should first construct the B instance. And this goes for the initialization list as well. So a constructor must look like this:

```
C::C(/* whatever */) : B(/* whatever */), /* construction of direct members of C */ { }
```

Now, for your specific list, as @ChrisMM suggests, it should be:

```
C::C(int c_, A cc_) : B(c_, A cc_), c(c_), cc(cc_) { }
```

These are the changes I made to your line:

1. To define the constructor, I referred to it as C::C(/*whatever*/), with *two* colon marks. That's a different symbol than a single colon mark - totally different meaning!
2. Construct B before anything else.
3. There is no such thing as a "nested initialization list", so you only use `:` once.
4. I made the constructor parameter names different than the field names, because when you choose the same names it's super-confusing. Also, it's a bad idea to have field names which are similar to class names but with different case. I realize you used these names for this example, but, well, that sets a bad example for others.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should do is rename your member-variables to something different than your constructor-argument-names; otherwise you will have a tough time disambiguating the member-variables from the arguments.

For example, in the code below (which does compile) I renamed all the member-variables to have an `m_` prefix, to make it obvious to the reader that they are member-variables and not something else.

Also note that its up to the `B` class's constructor to set the member-variables o the `B` object, so the `C` class constructor calls up to the appropriate `B` class constructor to do that, rather than trying to set `B`'s member-variables directly.

```
class A
{
protected:
   int m_a, m_aa;

public:
   A() {/* empty */}
   A(int a, int aa) : m_a(a), m_aa(aa) {/* empty */}
   ~A() {/* empty */}
};

class B
{
protected:
   int m_b;
   A m_bb;

public:
   B() {/* empty */}
   B(int b, A bb) : m_b(b), m_bb(bb) {/* empty */}
   ~B() {/* empty */}
};

class C: public B
{
private:
   int m_c;
   A m_cc;

public:
   C() {/* empty */}
   C(int c, A cc);
   ~C() {/* empty */}
};

C::C(int c, A cc)
   : B(c, cc)
   , m_c(c)
   , m_cc(cc)
{
   // empty
}

int main()
{
   A aaa(1, 2);
   C ccc(3, A(4,5)); ///how can i set values for B-members
}
```